# Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have written below code to connect SQL Server Database from Visual Studio using Python:

```
 import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=ReportServerTempDB;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute("select [User], [datetime] FROM [ReportServerTempDB].[dbo].
[DBUpgradeHistory]")

 for row in cur:
    print (row.user + "," + row.datetime)
    #print row[0] + "," + row[1]
   cur.close()
 con.close()
```

However, I'm getting an error like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "IronPythonApplication1.py",
>   line 2,in  con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL
>   Server};Server=localhost;Database=ReportServerTempDB;Trusted_Connection=yes')
>        pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
>         [DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) 
>         (SQLDriverConnect)')

**Note:** I have Windows Authentication to SQL Server, and I'm using VS 2015, and Python environment is IRON Python 64 bit 2.7

EDIT:
I changed driver as this: Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}
If I give like this in my code

```
for row in cur:
    print (row.user)
```

getting a new kind of error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IronPythonApplication1.py", line 6, in 
    for row in cur:
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: Attempt to use a closed cursor.

How to solve this?

Comment: Indenting is really important in python, and your example code is full of crappy indenting. Fix that first and try then again.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed it like this and its working:

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=ReportServer;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select userid,username from Users")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Comment: Switching the driver from {SQL Server} to {ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server} made it for me.